# redirect angular module to another module

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 different HTML pages with 2 different angular apps.
One page is for landing page and another for home page.The first page is rendered by the keycloak and I want to automatically redirect to another page and also inject the app1 module to 2nd module so, I can reuse app1 details.

```
var module = angular.module('product', []);

module.controller('GlobalCtrl', function(login) {
    this.loginService = login;
});

module.factory('login', function($q, $rootScope) {
    var keycloakAuth = new Keycloak('keycloak/keycloak.json');
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    keycloakAuth.init({onLoad: 'login-required'})
        .success(function() {
            console.log('Success', keycloakAuth);
            deferred.resolve()
        })
        .error(function(err) {
            console.error('Error', err, keycloakAuth);
            deferred.reject(err);
        });
    keycloakAuth.ready = deferred.promise
        .then(function() {
            if (keycloakAuth.authenticated) {
                keycloakAuth.loadUserProfile()
                    .success(function() {
                        console.log('User profile loaded');
                        $rootScope.$digest();
                    })
                    .error(function(err) {
                        console.log('Error loading user profile', err);
                    })
            }
        })
        .finally(function() {
            console.log('Finally');
            $rootScope.$digest();
        });
    return keycloakAuth;
});






angular
  .module('themesApp', [
    'theme',
    'theme.demos','product'
  ])
  .config(['$provide', '$routeProvider', function($provide, $routeProvider) {
    'use strict';
    $routeProvider
      .when('/newapp', {
        templateUrl: 'views/index1.html',
        resolve: {
          loadCalendar: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load([
              'bower_components/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js',
            ]);
          }]
        }
      })
      .when('/:templateFile', {
        templateUrl: function(param) {
          return 'views/' + param.templateFile + '.html';
        }
      })
      .when('#', {
        templateUrl: 'views/index1.html',
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/newapp'
      });
  }]);
```

How do I redirect one module to another?

Comment: you have to load html with `ng-app='app1'` and then use `bootstrap` method to load another module

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use simple javascript reload.

```
window.location="file2.html";
```

Please let me know if that is what you're looking for. Thank you.